# how to use the drag and drop functonality for android phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

i want to use drag and drop function in phonegap android application. 
I tried it in all ways but its not working.

i used this

```
<script>  
  $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

i included all the necessary files there but still its not working
i want to use drag and drop on table row

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in website i.e in web browser its working fine but on mobile application its not working.
Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been using jquery.ui it will work only on PC browsers, and wouldn't respond to touch. It you want to make it responsive to touch as well, you just need to include [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), in your head section after jQuery UI. And it should work fine. You can first test your app in Chrome simulator for various devices using ( Ctrl + Shift + I ) and selecting the desired device.

Hope this helps. Please mark as answer if this answers you.